# Cannot touch a specific filename, but also cannot remove it

Tags: bash, filesystems, samba, cifs, touch

I'm using a linux terminal on a mounted drive which (according to `df -Th` ) is of type "cifs"; let's say I'm in directory `/dir/`. I created a file `file_1`. Then I deleted it, and now I want to create it again, but I can't.

```
$ ls
# ^ nothing shows up
$ echo "test" > file_1
-bash: file_1: No such file or directory
```

which is a very weird error message. I know the file doesn't exist. I'm trying to create it now. Even if it *did* exist, I should be over-writing it. Similar problem with `touch`:

```
$ touch file_1
touch: cannot touch 'file_1': No such file or directory
```

If I try to remove the file:

```
$ rm file_1
rm: cannot remove 'file_1': No such file or directory
```

This at least makes sense: I can't remove a file that isn't showing up in `ls` (as far as I can tell, the file truly doesn't exist). But that means there's no way to *really* delete it, or reclaim the path. It's a crazy and contradictory situation that doesn't make any sense. Other files can be created:

```
$ touch file_2
$ echo " test" > file_3
$ ls
file_2  file_3
```

But I can't reclaim a crucial file path that I happen to need (`file_1` is specifically important for my workflow; I can't create it, but I also can't delete it). If I go one directory up to try to nuke the directory I get this:

```
$ rm *
$ ls
# ^ again, nothing. The directory appears empty
$ cd ..
$ rm -r dir/
rm: cannot remove 'dir/': Directory not empty
$ ls dir/
# nothing 
$ touch dir/file_2
$ ls dir/
file_2 
# ^ file_2 can be created, but not file_1
$ touch dir/file_1
touch: cannot touch 'dir/file_1': No such file or directory
# only this _specific_ filename is untouchable. What is going on ?!?!?
```

Same thing no matter how many directories I go up.
It's not the same error as the other common problem: `touch /path/to/folder/file_1` (I expect that error when `/path/to/` doesn't exist. That's not what's happening here. I'm in the directory `dir/` and working locally, it definitely exists.) This feels like an error that shouldn't be possible and it's brought all of my work to a grinding halt and I'm going crazy. Any help?

**Edit:** The problem went away as inexplicably as it came. I'm now able to touch `file_1` like any other path, but I can't see any change that would explain why.
I've had this happen before though, and I can't know when it will happen again. Somehow, filepaths that are created, then deleted, get "locked" into a status where they cannot be written to, until some significant amount of time later (a couple hours at least).
It eventually does resolve, but can cause major interruptions to work in progress.

Comment: CIFS is a network drive protocol, meaning the problem is quite likely either on the server hosting the drive, or in the interaction between your computer and that server. It's likely we can't debug this without access to the server, unless it's something obvious (like `file_1` actually being an illegal file name for the server; what *is* `file_1` in reality?)

Comment: Have you try to create file like `file.1` or `file-1`?

Comment: Try `ls -a` rather than just `ls`. If you have dot-files laying around that'd at least explain why you can't remove the directory and `rm *` wouldn't remove them, you'd need `rm *.*` to include them.

Comment: As @MarcusMüller stated, it's probably a problem (and very likely a bug) in the CIFS server, though it could also be a bug in the client (maybe related to caching). Try to following: 1. Try to write to the file from a different machine that has the same mount. If it fails, it's probably in the server side. If it works, there's possible a bug in the first client. In that case: 2. Check the mount options of the share (`grep <mountpoint> /proc/mounts`). 3. If you have root privileges, unmount the share and mount it again, repeat the test.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, you can try to workaround it by renaming the directory (`mv dir dir.old`) and create it again (`mkdir dir`). My guess is that since it's a new inode and dentry, the problem won't happen in the new directory (though the bug that lead to it might reoccur in the future if the root cause isn't found and fixed).

Comment: you can get `rm somefile` to give the "no such file or directory" error also if the working directory of your shell has been removed. (`mkdir foo; cd foo; rmdir ../foo; rm hello.txt` -> ENOENT)

Comment: "This feels like an error that shouldn't be possible" – In distributed systems, lots of strange things can happen that are impossible in local systems.

Comment: Regarding your update: Again, it might be related to caching issues on the server or the client. Next time it happened, you can check it the following way: As root, run on the client: `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to free the dentries and inodes cache from the kernel. Then check if the problem went away. If it did, it looks like a client issue (either a bug, or something that could be fixed in the mount options). If it didn't solve the problem, the bug is probably at the server side, and only the admins of the server could help.

Comment: Thanks aviro! I unfortunately can't reproduce the error state at will, but I'll try your command next time I encounter this problem and will post back here.